# How to implement relational views in same fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have 3 screen in my UI design.

Screen 1 : There will be a progress bar and information text in it.

Screen 2 : If operation is success, this screen will open and success message will be shown.

Screen 3 : If operation is fail, this screen will open and fail message will be shown.

These screens already have additional parts but I want to keep explanation simple.
As you can see, actually they don't have any hard operation, only show some informational texts and components.

There are 3 way in my mind.

Approach 1 : Create 3 fragments for every single operation.

Approach 2 : Create 1 fragment, create 1 layout, draw all views in the flow (progress, error, success) and manage them visible or gone.

Approach 3 : Create 1 fragment, create 3 different layout, in every next step, call onCreateView and inflate fragment with different layout.

Is there best approach for this kind of practices?

Comment: alertdialogs is exactly for this purpose. feel free to use them as u have an option to dismiss when u re done

Answer (score 0):

I will chose the second Approach.

In the first Approach I don't think is usual to manage 3 fragments to display just simple views, like TextView messages, you will complicate a simple task.

The third Approach is a good way too.

But I still think that is easier and simple you just make tha views visible or gone than every time inflate a new layout.

I chose for the second approach because is easier and clean to use.
You only need to set a global variable

```
private LinearLayout mMyView1
private LinearLayout mMyView2
private LinearLayout mMyView3

mMyView1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myid1);
mMyView2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myid2);

//than set visible or gone
mMyView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mMyView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Actually, I use your second approach in my app [GitHub](https://github.com/adleywd/WhatsNextSeries). So I recommend.
But keep in mind, if you want do more complex methods, need to review which approach is better.

**EDIT**

As [@uguboz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5923606/uguboz) commented, you can use other ways show a simple message, like [Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) or [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html)